# google analytics event tracking

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am tracking the success of CV contacted. I have the category, action and a label which are being called by script on 'success'. But the data is not collecting. I have the exact same set up for login and am able to track successful logins.

```
<div><h3>Success!</h3></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    successResumeContacted();
</script>

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Posting Contacted', 'CV Contacted', 'Success'])
```

I can see the script pushing the category, action and label. Is it an issue with space?
Does removing the label help?

From Firebug:

```
&utmt=event&utme=5(Posting%20Contacted*CV%20Contacted*Success)&
```

From the debugger console

_gaq.push processing "_trackEvent" for args: "[Posting Contacted,CV Contacted,Success]": [VM] ga_debug.js (19204):24 Track Event [VM] ga_debug.js (19204):24 Tracking beacon sent! utmwv=5.4.4d&utms=18&utmn=987355849&utmhn=ph.example.com&utmt=event&utme=5(Posting%20Contacted*CV%20Contacted*Success)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1280x1024&utmvp=1263x513&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=de&utmje=1&utmfl=11.8%20r800&utmdt=%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2%20CV%20of%20a%20jobseeker%20for%20test%201%20in%20Makati%20City%2C%20National%20Capital%20Region%20(%23132795388)%20%7C%20example&utmhid=792495776&utmr=0&utmp=%2FCV-for-test-in-Makati-City-a132795388&utmht=1379327109014&utmac=UA-XXXXX-X&utmcc=_utma%3D17022328.1635749529.1376896846.1378975684.1379324954.3%3B%2B_utmz%3D17022328.1376896847.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB~ [VM] ga_debug.js (19204):24 Account ID : UA-XXXXX-X Page Title : ••• CV of a jobseeker for test 1 in Makati City, National Capital Region (#132795388) | Example Host Name : ph.example.com Page : /CV-for-test-in-Makati-City-a132795388 Referring URL : 0 Hit ID : 792495776 Hit Type : event Event Name : Posting Contacted Event Type : CV Contacted Event Label : Success Visitor ID : 1635749529 Session Count : 3 Session Time - First : Mon Aug 19 2013 09:20:46 GMT 0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit) Session Time - Last : Thu Sep 12 2013 10:48:04 GMT 0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit) Session Time - Current : Mon Sep 16 2013 11:49:14 GMT 0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit) Campaign Time : Mon Aug 19 2013 09:20:47 GMT 0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit) Campaign Session : 1 Campaign Count : 1 Campaign Source : (direct) Campaign Medium : (none); Campaign Name : (direct) Language : de Encoding : UTF-8 Flash Version : 11.8 r800 Java Enabled : true Screen Resolution : 1280x1024 Browser Size : 1263x513 Color Depth : 32-bit Ga.js Version : 5.4.4d Cachebuster : 987355849 [VM] ga_debug.js (19204):24 _gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-180280-16]": [VM] ga_debug.js (19204):24 _gaq.push processing "_anonymizeIp" for args: "[]": [VM] ga_debug.js (19204):24 _gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]": [VM] ga_debug.js (19204):24 Track Pageview [VM] ga_debug.js (19204):24 Tracking beacon sent! utmwv=5.4.4d&utms=19&utmn=1649701917&utmhn=ph.example.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1280x1024&utmvp=1263x513&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=de&utmje=1&utmfl=11.8%20r800&utmdt=%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2%20CV%20of%20a%20jobseeker%20for%20test%201%20in%20Makati%20City%2C%20National%20Capital%20Region%20(%23132795388)%20%7C%20example&utmhid=792495776&utmr=0&utmp=%2FCV-for-test-in-Makati-City-a132795388&utmht=1379327109023&utmac=UA-xxxxx-16&utmcc=_utma%3D17022328.1635749529.1376896846.1378975684.1379324954.3%3B%2B_utmz%3D17022328.1376896847.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&aip=1&utmu=6AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB~ [VM] ga_debug.js (19204):24

Goal is set up as:
Category    equals to  Posting Contacted ,
Action          equals to  CV Contacted ,
Label           equals to  Success .

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Get the chrome extension "Google Analytics Debugger". Turn it on and reload the page. Watch to see if the tracking beacons are firing. Post full code so we can help you out further.

Comment: Thanks. I checked on the debugger that tracking beacons were sent. Here is my console log

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that there is anything wrong with the way the event is setup. I was able to test the event locally and it's firing off an event to GA. What does the script on 'success' look like? Are you sure you are looking at the correct profile?

Comment: I am looking at the correct profile. I can see that tracking beacon is sent. Updated the question with my console. Do I need to fix the goal?

Comment: Are you seeing the event come through on the real-time events report?

Comment: No I don't see this event on the Real time. Is there something wrong in the goal set up format? I have used the same format for other goals and they are capturing fine

Comment: The goal looks fine. Can you share the site?

Comment: ph.gigajob.com is my site and this is a CV contact action after login

Comment: Is it the Contact Now button? I found this by going to Find CVs (top nav) > clicked on a CV and then scrolled to the bottom.